# Subtle noise material

Tags: materials

I'm having a hard time creating a realistic material such as this one.

Do you have a suggestion how to achieve this kind of noisiness? Probably with an image of your node-setup?

Thank you :)

[image]

Comment: You can try to use the noise texture on a hige scale and use the colore ramp to set the color. Remember to plug in local cordenates so the textur don't move arund if you move the object, it's importent if you do an animation.

Comment: It seems to affect the specularity so I wouldn't alter the diffuse with noise, note how it changes depending on the normal.